# How can I reassign a variable in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, user-input

I am trying to make the code guess a number that the user has in mind. The code is supposed to take the average of a range, and the range should get shorter as it progresses. The trouble I have is with reassigning the range once the user inputs that the number is less than the guessed number. In my code below, after I run the function less(), I want high to be equal to new_high so the function can loop if the user inputs [less] again.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100")
low = 1
high = str(100)
new_high = 1
guess = int(0)
question = "Is your number [less] than, [more] than, or [equal] to", high, "?"

def less():
    new_high = (int(high) + int(low)) / 2
    print(float(new_high))
    new_high = int(new_high)
    return high == new_high

while guess <= 7:
    number = input("Is your number [less] than, [more] than, or [equal] to "+high+"? ")
    if number == "less":
        guess = guess + 1
        less()
        print(high)
    elif number == "equal":
        print("It took", guess, "guesses to guess the number.")
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently returning the boolean result of comparing high and new_high from the function less, and you aren't actually assigning that value to anything.

The below code should fix that.

```
print("Guess a number between 1 and 100")

low = 1
high = str(100)
new_high = 1
guess = int(0)
question = "Is your number [less] than, [more] than, or [equal] to", high, "?"

def less():
    new_high = (int(high) + int(low)) / 2
    print(float(new_high))
    new_high = int(new_high)
    return new_high

while guess <= 7:
    number = input(f"Is your number [less] than, [more] than, or [equal] to {high}? ")
    if number == "less":
        guess = guess + 1
        high = less()
        print(high)
    elif number == "equal":
        print("It took", guess, "guesses to guess the number.")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

> `return high == new_high`

You are returning a comparison, it is checking whether high is equal to new_high and return a boolean.

my previous answer was wrong.

`high = new_high`
`return high`

if you want to change the value of high, otherwise you can just return new_high